# Fullcalendar event classes

Tags: vue.js, sass, fullcalendar

For some reason fullcalendar doesnt add fc-h-event class to events in my "dayGridMonth" view:
[image]

which ends up looking bad:
[image] (the second event)

here are my options:

```
this.calendarOptions = {
      plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin],
      locale: gbrLocale,
      initialView: "dayGridMonth",
      headerToolbar: {
        start: "",
        center: "",
        end: ""
      },
      selectable: true,
      events: this.fetchEvents,
      editable: true,
      showNonCurrentDates: false,
      eventResizableFromStart: true,
      dragScroll: true,
      dayMaxEvents: 2,
      navLinks: true,
      dateClick: this.openAddNewEvent,
      eventClick: this.openEditEvent,
      eventDrop: this.eventDrop,
      eventResize: this.eventResize
    };
```

Any idea how to add this class in this view, or can u see mistake in my options?

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDisplay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for option:

```
eventDisplay: "block"
```

Documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDisplay

Answer (score 1):

It should be a normal behaviour where full day event is highlighted while time range event is marked with circle dot.

Here is the Codesandbox example with 2 types of event.

https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-darkness-fyfrz?file=/src/components/Calendar.vue